# Is a list page usually called an archive page in Wordpress?

Tags: archives, list

If I have a custom content type of events, and I want a  page that shows all the events, is this known as an archive in Wordpress?

This would be the link http://example.dev/?post_type=event that brings up my list of events and this uses the archive template? Am I correct?

Answer (score 3):

In the true sense, the word *archive* refers to a dynamic virtual page of posts like the home, category, taxonomy, date, author, tag and custom post type archive pages. These are pages that are not created like standard pages in the back end. These pages displays an archive of posts according to the page requested in URL and displays content dynamically according to post date.

Non archive pages are real pages which you can create in admin, and are static pages. These pages displays static content and needs to be manually updated to display different content. Although custom queries and shortcodes are used to display custom dynamic content on pages, these pages are still static as these custom queries are not controlled and influenced by the page request in URL. The main query object (*which contol the default content that will be displayed*) will remain static and will not change exept when the page content is modified in the backend.

There are two scenarios here then to look at:

**Scenario 1:**

If you create an `archive.php` or `archive-{$post_type}.php` template and you have set `has_archive` when you registed the post type, this templates will be used to display posts from the custom post type. This will be an archive of post type posts, ie, a true archive page

**Scenario 2:**

If you created a custom page in backend and used a custom query to display posts from the custom post type, this will not be an archive page. This will be like an index page, basically the same as the first page in a book that will be listing the index of the book